# react-native-router-flux with redux, how to dispatch action on route?

Tags: react-native, redux, react-native-router-flux

I have a list of users on one screen https://screencast.com/t/RQp8IrWdV5qf, when you click any item of the list it shows single user by dispatching `showProfile` action with id of the user as you can see by ListItem code:

```
import React, {Component, PropTypes} from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import {StyleSheet, View, Text, Image, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native'
import {Actions} from 'react-native-router-flux'
import { showProfile } from '../../actions'

const ListItem = ({ user, dispatch }) => {
    return (
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.container}
            onPress={() => {
                dispatch(showProfile(user.id));
                Actions.profile();
            }}
        >
            <View style={styles.left}>
                <Image style={styles.image} source={{uri:user.avatar.thumb}} />
                <View style={styles.text}>
                    <Text style={styles.title}>{user.display_name}</Text>
                </View>
            </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    )
}

ListItem.propTypes = {
    dispatch: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    user: PropTypes.object.isRequired
}

export default connect()(ListItem);
```

What I would like is, when I click tab "Profile" at the bottom right corner, to open profile of user with specific id (logged in user):

```
import React from 'react'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import configureStore from './configureStore'
import { Router, Scene, Route } from 'react-native-router-flux'
import Members from './components/Members/List'
import Profile from './components/Profile'
import { Text } from 'react-native'
import { showProfile } from './actions'

const Kernel = () => (
  <Provider store={configureStore()}>
      <Router>
        <Scene key="root">
          {/* Tab Container */}
          <Scene
            key="tabbar"
            tabs={true}
            tabBarStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF' }}
          >
            {/* Tab and it's scenes */}
            <Scene key="members" title="Members" icon={TabIcon} component={Members} initial={true}>
            </Scene>
            {/* Removed for brevity */}
            {/* Tab and it's scenes */}
            <Scene key="profile" title="Profile" icon={TabIcon} component={Profile} onEnter={dispatch(showProfile(1))}>
            </Scene>
            {/* Removed for brevity */}
          </Scene>
        </Scene>
      </Router>
  </Provider>
)
```

As you can see I am trying to do something like `onEnter={dispatch(showProfile(1))}`. What is right way to do this?

Comment: Could you set default props of the current user in the Profile component? Otherwise couldn't you just put Actions.profile({1}) in the onPress action of the 'profile' tab button?

Comment: @MichaelGalos thanks, this gave me ideas for solution.

Answer (score 0):

Got it done with this piece of code:

```
let TabIcon = ({ selected, title, dispatch }) => {
    if(title == "Profile") {
        return (
            <Text
                style={{color: selected ? 'red' :'black'}}
                onPress={() => {
                    if(title == "Profile") {
                        dispatch(showProfile(1));
                        Actions.profile();
                    }
                }}
            >{title}</Text>
        );
    }
    return (
        <Text
            style={{color: selected ? 'red' :'black'}}
        >{title}</Text>
    );
}

TabIcon = connect()(TabIcon);
```